# Find the co-ordinates on a line at the closest point to another point in R

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, spatial

Working in R I have 2 objects, a SpatialLinesDataFrame (representing a road network) and a SpatialPointsDataFrame (representing object locations). I need to output the co-ordinates on the road of the point closest to each of the object locations.

All I can find from searches are methods for doing this in other languages (e.g. Python - [How to find the closest point on a line segment to an arbitrary point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931007/how-to-find-the-closest-point-on-a-line-segment-to-an-arbitrary-point)) or for finding the minimum distance between the points and line (e.g. using `geosphere::dist2Line()` or `rgeos::gDistance()`). I am interested simply in returning the co-ordinates of the nearest point on the line.

EDIT:
Here is a small subset of my road network:

```
new("SpatialLinesDataFrame"
    , data = structure(list(ID = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                            ET_ID = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"),
                            length = c(0.280848, 0.812133, 0.0402004, 0.209611, 0.0433089, 0.501865, 0.363501)),
                       .Names = c("ID", "ET_ID", "length"),
                       row.names = c(980L, 982L, 983L, 984L, 987L, 988L, 989L),
                       class = "data.frame")
, lines = list(<S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
               <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
               <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
               <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
               <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
               <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>, 
               <S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>)
, bbox = structure(c(433266.568837884, 547825.73420664, 437050.511867258, 548168.921069476),
                   .Dim = c(2L, 2L),
                   .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max")))
, proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
)
```

and of my object locations:

```
new("SpatialPointsDataFrame"
    , data = structure(list(x = c(38.4129, 38.41697, 38.41501), y = c(4.95659, 4.95809, 4.96122)),
                       .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(105L, 166L, 185L), class = "data.frame")
    , coords.nrs = numeric(0)
    , coords = structure(c(434912.0166297, 435363.392542353, 435146.398500838, 547894.637850701, 548060.055746692, 548406.25007762),
                         .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("105", "166", "185"), c("x", "y")))
    , bbox = structure(c(434912.0166297, 547894.637850701, 435363.392542353, 548406.25007762),
                       .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max")))
    , proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you care to share an example of your data?

Comment: Sure, I'll just try and output it

Comment: Do the answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782488/r-calculating-the-shortest-distance-between-two-point-layers) help? Or the `dist2line` function in the `geosphere` package.

Comment: are you looking for `nearestPointOnLine` in the `maptools` package? You'll have to fettle your `SpatialLinesDF` a bit though. Also, your pasted data won't work because S4 objects aren't printed out.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, I think that does what I want, but doesn't work automatically for geographic coordinates. I assume I can use `@coords` for the point coordinates, but I'm not sure how to output the coordinates for the lines.

Comment: Ah, `snapPointsToLines` works with `Spatial*` objects. You need geometric (projected) coordinates since it doesn't work with lat-long. Only a problem if working on a data set with a large extent on the globe...

Comment: Thanks - `maptools::snapPointsToLines` does the job. My study region is a small area, so no problems with extent.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind implementing this yourself, porting from this pseudo-code...

```
Point snap_to_segment(Point point, Segment segment):
    Point s1 = segment.start;
    Point s2 = segment.end;

    Vector v = s2 - s1;
    Vector w = point - s1;

    double c1 = Vector.dot_product(w,v);
    double c2 = Vector.dot_product(v,v);

    Point snap;

    if c1 <= 0:
        snap = s1

    elif c2 <= c1:
        snap = s2

    else:
        snap = s1 + v * (c1 / c2)

    return snap
```

Besides that, I have done much better in Python than the funcion above when I decided to use Shapely. As it turns out:

> [rgeos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/rgeos.pdf) is the R counterpart to Python's Shapely. Both Shapely and rgeos are based on GEOS (i.e. the PostGIS engine) ([source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168609/8254))

...however, in Shapely I find the desired point like this:

```
desiredPoint = road.distance(road.project(point));
```

but `rgeos` seem to lack both the `linestring.project(point)` and `linestring.distance(scalarValue)` methods...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick hack of heltonbiker's answer in R (a 2D version) for those who might need it. Better would be to use a library of course, but sometimes you don't want to and if all you need is to get the nearest point on a line, this will do it.

```
findClosestPtToSeg <- function( ptx,pty, sx0,sy0,sx1,sy1 ){

  sdx <- sx1-sx0
  sdy <- sy1-sy0
  wx <- ptx-sx0
  wy <- pty-sy0

  lambda <- (wx*sdx + wy*sdy) / (sdx*sdx + sdy*sdy)
  trunclamb <- min(max(lambda,0),1)

  rv <- list() # return the coordinates in a list
  rv$x <- sx0 + trunclamb*sdx
  rv$y <- sy0 + trunclamb*sdy
  return(rv)
}
```

And here is some output on a few test cases:

```
> findClosestPtToSeg( 1,2, 0,0,1,1 )
$x
[1] 1
$y
[1] 1

> findClosestPtToSeg( -1,-2, 0,0,1,1 )
$x
[1] 0
$y
[1] 0

> findClosestPtToSeg( 0.5,0.6, 0,0,1,1 )
$x
[1] 0.55
$y
[1] 0.55
```

Note that it is not beautiful code, it doesn't check for a degenerate interval and handles the input points differently (passed by coordinate) than the return value (packed in a list with names). Oh well, it was a quick hack and worked fine for me.

Make sure that heltonbiker gets any upvotes too if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vectorized n-dimensional version of heltonbiker's method. It also returns the distance from `p4` to `p3` and the fraction of the distance from `p4` to `p1` relative to the distance from `p1` to `p2`, where `p3` is the target point and `p4` is the found closest point.

```
nrow=1e5
ncol=10

p1=matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow)
p2=matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow)
p3=rnorm(ncol)

p21=p2-p1
p31=outer(rep(1,nrow(p1)),p3)-p1
c1=rowSums(p31*p21)
c2=rowSums(p21*p21)
frac=c1/c2
p4=p1+p21*frac

# uncomment to restrict points to the line segment between p1 and p2
# o1=c1>c2;u0=c1<0;p4[o1]=p1[o1];frac[o1]=1;p4[u0]=p2[u0];frac[u0]=0

dist=sqrt(outer(rowSums(p4^2),sum(p3^2),"+")-tcrossprod(p4,2*t(p3)))[,1]
```

`outer(rep(1,nrow(m)),v)-m` is a fast way to apply a row-wise arithmetic operation between a vector and each row of a matrix (see [/questions/39443055/add-a-vector-to-all-rows-of-a-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443055/add-a-vector-to-all-rows-of-a-matrix)).

`sqrt(outer(rowSums(m^2),sum(v^2),"+")-tcrossprod(m,2*t(v)))[,1]` is a fast way to calculate the Euclidean distance of a vector `v` to each row in matrix `m`.

Not vectorized:

```
p1=c(1,5,2,4)
p2=c(7,3,2,5)
p3=c(5,5,2,3)

p21=p2-p1
p31=p3-p1
c1=(p31%*%p21)[1]
c2=(p21%*%p21)[1]
frac=c1/c2
p4=p1+p21*frac
# if(c1>c2){p4=p1;frac=0};if(c1<0){p4=p1;frac=1}
dist=sqrt(sum((p31-frac*p21)^2))
list(p4,frac,dist)
```